# PHP and Modules API Mismatch on CentOS

Tags: nginx, centos, php

I have been using Centmin to help manage my web server for a while now. I just recently started up a dev server to update my current production server. Right now I am having issues trying to get php 5.4.27 and its modules to work. Currently the only two modules that are throwing errors on php-fpm restart are memcache and memcached.

The server is running Nginx and PHP-FPM

```
Starting php-fpm [24-Apr-2014 11:31:02] NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: memcache: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20090626
PHP    compiled with module API=20100525
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
[24-Apr-2014 11:31:02] NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: memcached: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20090626
PHP    compiled with module API=20100525
These options need to match
```

I have tried pecl upgrade, uninstall and install of the modules. I have as well tried to use yum to install them. What can I do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors you are receiving is because the module you are attempting to install/upgrade was built using a different version of PHP.

Either install the same version of PHP for which the modules were built with OR simply compile the modules manually which is quite easy to do.

```
1) Download pecl module and untar
2) cd into module directory and phpize
3) ./configure
4) make && make install
```

Make sure the modules are install into the proper extensions directory too so the php.ini can load them. Some pecl modules have specific ./configure options too, you can check those by running `./configure --help` before compilation.